# `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` when referencing existing javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot

**Important edit at bottom of some strange behavior.**

---

I'm trying to include a javascript file into my html via a `<script>` tag and I'm getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

In case it matters, I'm using the Velocity templating engine.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

**Here is my directory structure.**

[image: Directory]

---

**Here is my index.vm file.**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Velocity Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" onkeydown="filter(this)"></input>
    #foreach ($person in $personList)
        <div>
            <h4>$person.name</h4>
        </div>
    #end
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**And here is the javascript file.**

```
function filter(element) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/updateFilter?filter=' + element.value,
        success: location.reload(true),
        error: location.reload(true)
    })
}
```

---

Editing to add this image. For some reason this is the `filter.js` file when I inspect the sources in Chrome.

[image: Chrome sources]

---

EDIT: For some reason, every request other than the one I have mapped to the controller, including `filter.js`, is returning the raw html from `index.vm`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Open chrome dev tools and check what exact url is requested and what response is generated for it.

Comment: Is it possible to use `.getJSON` instead?

Comment: your server is sending the wrong file by the looks of it

Comment: @zerkms added request/response. 

@JaromandaX There is only one request mapping written in the controller and only one `.vm` file in project.

Comment: What url is requested?

Comment: `localhost:8080` - I added an image at the bottom of the main post.

Comment: On the other screenshot the name of the resource is `filter.js`, so it cannot be `http://localhost:8080/`. Show a screenshot with all requests emitted.

Comment: I added a screenshot that reveals what's happening. Every request is returning and displaying the raw html except for the root/index.vm request. I've also updated the tags to include spring as I suppose that would be what's causing this.

Comment: Have you configured routing for your static files?

Answer (score -1):

You have an unnecessary closing tag for your  element - pasting your html into plnkr highlights this.

I would also perform a "trial and error" process of elimination, as it may not be the inclusion of the JS file that is the cause.

Comment: Plnkr highlights the input closing tag, but it is just being ignored. Also, commenting out the inclusion of the JS file results in no errors.

Comment: I realise plnkr ignores the closing tag, as would be expected. The trial and error approach would still be worthwhile though, assuming there are no other suitable answers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "trial and error". Of course I've tried a lot of trials and recieved a lot of errors. If someone has gotten to the point in a problem where there posting on here, telling someone to use the "trial and error" method doesn't really contribute much. I posted on here in hopes that someone else can see what I'm doing wrong since I've exhausted all of my trial and error attempts.

Comment: Does the error occur when first loading the html or only when the onkeydown event is triggered ?